# java cannot access javax.persistence.PersistenceException from Hibernate code

Tags: java, hibernate, compiler-errors

I'm setting up a very simple project, just trying to get a basic Hibernate setup without maven. I've downloaded the jar, put it under a /lib directory within my project and added this directory as a library under module settings. I can access Hibernate's classes and compile the project.

However, after declaring that the method throws a `HibernateException` (that extends `PersistenceException`), the code doesn't compile:

### HibernateStatesMain.java:

```
package example;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateStatesMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws HibernateException {
        Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
    }
}
```

And when I build, I get:

```
Error:(11, 24) java: cannot access javax.persistence.PersistenceException
  class file for javax.persistence.PersistenceException not found
```

This should be a very simple thing, but I can't get my head around it. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Project setup]

[image: Error]

Comment: check once, is there **ejb3-persistence.jar** in lib?

Comment: @SandipND You're right, I was missing a jar. I thought PersistenceException would be in the JDK.

Comment: check now if not working, comment here

Comment: try to work with maven, easy to build.

Comment: @SandipND Yes, but I'm too used to maven, that's why I'm trying to set it up manually.

Comment: If you don't want to use maven then try ivy. But managing jar files manually should be a thing of the past.